# ball count roll a ball

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a roll-a-ball game where the ball moves and it counts when the ball collides with the cubes. I need for the game to count every time the ball moves but I can't seem to figure it out. I keep getting errors. I appreciate any help.
using UnityEngine;

```
// Include the namespace required to use Unity UI
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Create public variables for player speed, and for the Text UI game objects
    public float speed;
    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;
    public Text movesText;

    // Create private references to the rigidbody component on the player, and the count of pick up objects picked up so far
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;
    private int moves;
    private float location;

    // At the start of the game..
    void Start()
    {
        // Assign the Rigidbody component to our private rb variable
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Set the count to zero 
        count = 0;

        // Set moves to zero
        moves = 0;

        // Run the SetCountText function to update the UI (see below)
        SetCountText();

        // Set the text property of our Win Text UI to an empty string, making the 'You Win' (game over message) blank
        winText.text = "";

        location = transform.location;

        SetMovesText();


    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (location != transform.location)
        {
            moves = moves + 1;
            location = transform.location;
            SetMovesText();
        }



    }

    // Each physics step..
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Set some local float variables equal to the value of our Horizontal and Vertical Inputs
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Create a Vector3 variable, and assign X and Z to feature our horizontal and vertical float variables above
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        // Add a physical force to our Player rigidbody using our 'movement' Vector3 above, 
        // multiplying it by 'speed' - our public player speed that appears in the inspector
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    // When this game object intersects a collider with 'is trigger' checked, 
    // store a reference to that collider in a variable named 'other'..
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // ..and if the game object we intersect has the tag 'Pick Up' assigned to it..
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            // Make the other game object (the pick up) inactive, to make it disappear
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            // Add one to the score variable 'count'
            count = count + 1;

            // Run the 'SetCountText()' function (see below)
            SetCountText();

        }

    }

    // Create a standalone function that can update the 'countText' UI and check if the required amount to win has been achieved
    void SetCountText()
    {
        // Update the text field of our 'countText' variable
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();

        // Check if our 'count' is equal to or exceeded 12
        if (count >= 12)
        {
            // Set the text value of our 'winText'
            winText.text = "You Win!";
        }

    }

    void SetMovesText()
    {
        movesText.text = "Moves: " + moves.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat to use syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as `transform.location` in Unity. I believe you want to get the position of the object. This is done with `transform.position` and the rotation of an object can be modified with `transform.rotation`.

> I need for the game to count every time the ball moves

You can do this by checking when `transform.position` changes.

Here are the changes that needs to be made based on what I said above:

**1**.Change your `private float location;` to `private Vector3 location;`

**2**.Change `location = transform.location;` to `location = transform.position;`

**3**.Change `if (location != transform.location)` to `if (location != transform.position)`

**4**.Finally change `location = transform.location;` to `location = transform.position;`.

The fixed code:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Create public variables for player speed, and for the Text UI game objects
    public float speed;
    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;
    public Text movesText;

    // Create private references to the rigidbody component on the player, and the count of pick up objects picked up so far
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;
    private int moves;
    private Vector3 location;

    // At the start of the game..
    void Start()
    {
        // Assign the Rigidbody component to our private rb variable
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Set the count to zero 
        count = 0;

        // Set moves to zero
        moves = 0;

        // Run the SetCountText function to update the UI (see below)
        SetCountText();

        // Set the text property of our Win Text UI to an empty string, making the 'You Win' (game over message) blank
        winText.text = "";
        location = transform.position;
        SetMovesText();
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (location != transform.position)
        {
            moves = moves + 1;
            location = transform.position;
            SetMovesText();
        }
    }

    // Each physics step..
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Set some local float variables equal to the value of our Horizontal and Vertical Inputs
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Create a Vector3 variable, and assign X and Z to feature our horizontal and vertical float variables above
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        // Add a physical force to our Player rigidbody using our 'movement' Vector3 above, 
        // multiplying it by 'speed' - our public player speed that appears in the inspector
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    // When this game object intersects a collider with 'is trigger' checked, 
    // store a reference to that collider in a variable named 'other'..
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // ..and if the game object we intersect has the tag 'Pick Up' assigned to it..
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            // Make the other game object (the pick up) inactive, to make it disappear
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            // Add one to the score variable 'count'
            count = count + 1;

            // Run the 'SetCountText()' function (see below)
            SetCountText();
        }
    }

    // Create a standalone function that can update the 'countText' UI and check if the required amount to win has been achieved
    void SetCountText()
    {
        // Update the text field of our 'countText' variable
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();

        // Check if our 'count' is equal to or exceeded 12
        if (count >= 12)
        {
            // Set the text value of our 'winText'
            winText.text = "You Win!";
        }

    }

    void SetMovesText()
    {
        movesText.text = "Moves: " + moves.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You really saved me a ton of stress.

Comment: @Brandi If this answer helped you, accept it as an answer. It helps people that might have the same question to find an answer quicker and it's a nice "Thank you" to the person who took the time to respond.